# CoffeeScript checking to see if value entered is 4 or 5 digits long?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Right now this statement is checking to see if the number entered (`sn_val`) is 4 digits long:

```
if bin_model isnt "Accessories" and (sn_val.length isnt 4 or !$.isNumeric(sn_val))
```

Does anyone know how I could get it to allow numbers of either 4 or 5 digits in length? I've tried this `(sn_val.length isnt 4 or 5 or !$.isNumeric(sn_val))` and this `(sn_val.length isnt 4 or sn_val.length isnt 5 or !$.isNumeric(sn_val))` but neither of these seemed to work. I'm new to CoffeeScript so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not convert it to a number and test if it's between `1000` and `99999`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using this line instead:

`else if bin_model isnt "Accessories" and ((!sn_val.match(/^[0-9]{4,5}$/)) or !$.isNumeric(sn_val))`

https://forums.asp.net/t/1824542.aspx?+0+9+1+3+Regular+Expression+Interpret+Please is where I got the help from.